# Fading in and out Web Audio Loop

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm recording some audio in the browser and then want to loop it seamlessly, avoiding clicks etc when starting. This means fading it and out.

I can ramp the volume up and down once, but I can't find anyway to trigger Web Audio's 'ramp to value at time' every time the loop starts again.

Is there an easy way to do this? I've got 10 of these buffers looping so I'd like to avoid lots of costly setinterval checks if possible...

```
            let source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
            let gain = audioContext.createGain();
            gain.gain.value = 0.01;

            source.buffer = decodedData;
            songLength = decodedData.duration;

            source.loop = true;
            source.connect(gain);
            gain.connect(audioContext.destination);
            source.start(0);
        
            // fade in and out
            gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.2, audioContext.currentTime + 1);
            gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.01, audioContext.currentTime + songLength);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider listening to the [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioScheduledSourceNode/ended_event) event and re-trigger the playback:

```js
class FadeInLoop {
  ctx
  audioBuffer
  gainNode
  isPlaying = true

  constructor(ctx, url) {
    this.ctx = ctx
    this.audioBuffer = fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
      .then(arrayBuffer => ctx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))

    this.gainNode = ctx.createGain()
    this.gainNode.connect(ctx.destination)
  }

  async start() {
    this.isPlaying = true
    const source = ctx.createBufferSource()
    this.source = source
    source.addEventListener('ended', e => {
      if (this.isPlaying) { // repeat unless stop() was called
        this.start()
      }
    })

    source.connect(this.gainNode)
    source.buffer = await this.audioBuffer
    const now = this.ctx.currentTime
    this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(Number.EPSILON, now);
    this.gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, now + 0.055)
    source.start(0)
  }

  stop() {
    this.isPlaying = false
    this.source?.stop()
  }
}

const ctx = new AudioContext({ latencyHint: 'interactive' })
const loop = new FadeInLoop(ctx, 'https://batman.dev/static/71474264/loop.mp3')
```

```html
<button onclick="loop.start()">Start</button>
<button onclick="loop.stop()">Stop</button>
```

Comment: I've added this in but it never seems to be triggered? In the API specs I can't see any 'ended' event, but maybe I've missed something simple...
`source.addEventListener('ended', () => {
                console.log("fade in");
                // playback ended, restart playback and trigger fade in/out
                // fade in and out
                    gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.2, audioContext.currentTime + 1);
                    gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.01, audioContext.currentTime + songLength);
            })`

Comment: Ah from reading the docs, it looks like that only triggers on source.stop(), not when coming back to the start of the loop... 

It looks like someone else flagged this back in 2013, but it got rejected as an addition to the spec. https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/267

Seems like a bad call, as this is pretty basic functionality in other looping software. I wonder if an ADSR envelope could do what I need...

Comment: See the above changes which exemplify a loop with white noise at the beginning.

Comment: For Firefox you'd need to `setValueAtTIme(Number.EPSILON, now)`, they throw when we exponentialRampToValue from `0`.

Comment: Nice. Updated and it also removed a click in the beginning on Chrome 

Comment: Amazing. Works great. Thanks for your help. This pattern should be helpful for others doing looping work in Web Audio too.

Comment: All hail the [Sheikah Sensor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NplzsNsJ_w&t=75s)